# `tf.data.Dataset` only supports Python-style iteration in eager mode or within tf.function

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
RuntimeError: `tf.data.Dataset` only supports Python-style iteration in eager mode or within tf.function.
```

please help with this error as I am not sure what to do

here is the offending line:

```
for input_example_batch, target_example_batch in dataset.take(1):
```

Comment: it should be used in a decorated function `@tf.function
def do_stuff():` should also work in most tf classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#take), `dataset.take(n)` returns *another dataset*, not a single batch. To actually get a batch out of that single-batch dataset, you can do

```
for input_example_batch, target_example_batch in next(iter(dataset.take(1))):
```

Comment: Actually, you can directly iterate over a `tf.data.Dataset` without creating an `iterator`.